# Android ListView Row with text and row with images

Tags: android, listview, layout, rows

My problem is I have a ListView in an Activity and now I load text in rows but in one of those rows, I need to load some thumbnails. These thumbs must be clickable to see larger images in another Activity.

I cannot load text in the first row of the ListView and thumbs in the second.

Anyone can help?

Comment: It may be possible to reference an array list, which will reference the correct variables, to propagate the `ListView`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by defining a custom Adapter, defining different viewType, for instance:

```
public class MyAdapter extends Adapter {

    // [implement required methods]

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
          if (/* specific row */) {
              return 1;
          }
          return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
          View rowView;
          if (/* specific row */) {
               rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_image,
                parent, false);
          } else {
               rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_text,
                parent, false);
          }
          // etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: This helped me. Now, my adventure is show the images in the row. I cannot until now...

The images url are stored in an ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by making changes in you adapter class. In that class you have to set some logic inside `getView()` method so that the images get displayed where ever you want. And you have to display the image programmatically because if you set the imagview in your xml then you must have to set image in every imageview. 
This is my opinion, there could be a smarter way to do this. I am new to android.